# Como acessar a imagem do print screen?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, imagem

Quando apertamos a tecla <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> do nosso teclado, a imagem da tela fica salva em algum cache, em memória, em algum lugar, pois quando damos <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> após, no Paint por exemplo ela apararece, como acessar o local e "pegar" a imagem de lá em C#?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quando você usa a tecla *Print Screen*, uma cópia do que está na tela vai para a [**Área de Transferência**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rea_de_transfer%C3%AAncia). É o mesmo lugar para onde vai qualquer informação que você copia ou recorta.

Em .NET, você pode acessar e interagir com a área de transferência através de algumas classes que possuem o mesmo nome, embora estejam em *namespaces* diferentes. As que eu conheço são:

- [`System.Windows.Clipboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (clipboard é o nome da área de transferência em inglês);
- [`System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Note que os métodos são basicamente os mesmos. Você pode verificar o tipo do conteúdo na área de transferência - `ContainsImage` lhe dirá se é uma imagem - e com o método `GetImage` você obtém um objeto que contém sua imagem.

Answer (score 10):

Um código pronto para uso complementando a resposta do Renan:

```
using static System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat; //Somente à partir do C# 6
using static System.Clipboard; //Somente à partir do C# 6, caso contrário, use apenas o namespace

if (ContainsImage())  
    GetImage().Save(@"image.jpeg", Jpeg);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Drawing/PrintScreen.cs)

Você pode ainda usar uma [solução mais completa](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39197/Print-Screen-in-C).

Antes do C# 6 deve fazer a importação do *namespace*, mas não da classe estática).

Comment: Corrija-me se estiver errado, mas acredito que você confundiu ao utilizar o `using` ao correto `using static`, pois os membros abaixo não estão declarados e provavelmente causaria um erro na compilação.

Comment: @CypherPotato quando eu fiz isso ainda estava criando esse recurso e no começo era sem o `static`, depois que decidiram exigir o `static` neste contexto. Obrigado.